# pydub audio glitches when splitting/joining mp3

Tags: python, audio-streaming, pydub

I'm experimenting with pydub, which I like very much, however I am having a problem when splitting/joining an mp3 file.

I need to generate a series of small snippets of audio on the server, which will be sent in sequence to a web browser and played via an `<audio/>` element. I need the audio playback to be 'seamless' with no audible joins between the separate pieces. At the moment however, the joins between the separate bits of audio are quite obvious, sometimes there is a short silence and sometimes a strange audio glitch.

In my proof of concept code I have taken a single large mp3 and split it into 1-second chunks as follows:

```
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3('my.mp3')
song_pos = 0
while song_pos < 100:
    p1 = song_pos * 1000
    p2 = p1 + 1000

    segment = song[p1:p2] # 1 second of audio

    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    segment.export(output, format="mp3")
    client_data = output.getvalue() # send this to client

    song_pos += 1
```

The client_data values are streamed to the browser over a long-lived http connection:

```
socket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n\r\n")
```

and then for each new chunk of audio

```
socket.send(client_data)
```

Can anyone explain the glitches that I am hearing, and suggest a way to eliminate them?

Comment: Switching from one track to another without a smooth crossover/fadein will create cracking sounds. Have you tried windowing your segments?`segment.fade_in(100).fade_out(100)`

Comment: Also, it looks as if you are creating multiple MP3 files (headers, metadata etc.) and sending them one after another in one stream. I wouldn't expect all browsers to be able to decipher that. Instead you should create one common MP3 stream and append samples to it.

Comment: The issue is that MP3 codecs used by ffmpeg add silence to the end of the encoded audio (and your approach is producing multiple individual audio files). If possible use a lossless format like wave, and then use something like gzip to reduce the file size

Comment: @Jiaaro thanks, that explains the silences I hear, but sometimes there are also audible glitches - any idea about those? (if you want to answer rather than comment I can award you some bounty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

The primary issue is that MP3 codecs used by ffmpeg add silence to the end of the encoded audio (and your approach is producing multiple individual audio files).

If possible, use a lossless format like wave and then reduce the file size with gzip or similar. You may also be able to use lossless audio compression (for example, flac) but it probably depends on how the encoder works.

I don't have a conclusive explanation for the audible artifacts you're hearing, but it could be that you're splitting the audio at a point where the signal is non-zero. If a sound begins with a sample with a value of 100 (for example), that would sound like a digital popping sound. The MP3 compression may also alter the sound though, especially at lower bit rates. If this is the issue, a 1ms fade in will eliminate the pop without a noticeable audible "fade" (though potentially introduce other artifacts) -  a longer fade in (like 20 or 50 ms would avoid strange frequency domain artifacts but would introduce noticeable a "fade in".

If you're willing to do a little more (coding) work, you can search for a "zero crossing" (basically, a place where the signal is at a zero point naturally) and split the audio there.

**Probably the best approach if it's possible:**

Encode the entire signal as a single, compressed file, and send the bytes (of that one file) down to the client in chunks for playback as a single stream. If you use constant bitrate mp3 encoding (CBR) you can send almost perfectly 1 second long chunks just by counting bytes. e.g., with 256kbps CBR, just send 256 KB at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So, I could be totally wrong I don't usually mess with audio files but it could be an indexing issue. try,

```
p2 = p1 + 1001
```

but you may need to invert the concatenation process for it to work. Unless you add an extra millisecond on the end.

The only other thing I would think it could be is an artifact in the stream that enters when you convert the bytes to string. Try, using the AudioSegment().raw_data endpoint for a bytes representation of the audio.

Answer (score -1):

Sound is waveform and you are connecting two waves that are out of phase from one another; so you get a step function and that makes the pop.

I'm unfamiliar with this software but codifying Nils Werner's suggestions, you might try:

```
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3('my.mp3')
song_pos = 0

# begin with a millisecond of blank
segment = AudioSegment.silent(duration=1)
# append all your pieces to it
while song_pos < 100:
    p1 = song_pos * 1000
    p2 = p1 + 1000
    #append an item to your segment with several milliseconds of crossfade
    segment.append(song[p1:p2], crossfade=50)
    song_pos += 1

# then pass it on to your client outside of your loop
output = StringIO.StringIO()
segment.export(output, format="mp3")
client_data = output.getvalue() # send this to client
```

depending upon how low/high the frequency of what you're joining you'll need to adjust the crossfade time to blend; low frequency will require more fade.

Comment: I hear the pop when I split/rejoin a single mp3 file, the sound inside an mp3 is split into many tiny samples so when I rejoin the 2 parts of the file I don't think there is any reason for a pop to appear, the 2 samples that used to be adjacent to each other should again be adjacent producing an identical sound

Comment: yes, but you're cutting up compressed audio, not lossless audio, so I"m not sure that holds true.   perhaps you could avoid by treating as a compression issue? wouldn't a better solution to joining audio be to move to a lossless format such as WAV; make your splits... then recompile as an mp3? see: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24270/what-are-the-advantages-of-wav-vs-mp3 "use WAV for recording and editing"